# PowerShell copy and run

Tags: powershell

I want to copy the "AccessRunTime.exe" to the local C drive then run a script to install it as an Administrator. (local users who are using the PC do not have administrative rights.)

I don't know where to look for executing the script

```
 c:\accessruntime2010\setup.exe /config c:\accessruntime2010\config.xml
```

Thanks

(I can copy the files so I don't need help with that. I need help with figuring out how to run the command above as admin while a user is logged in or not)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Process = "c:\accessruntime2010\setup.exe"
$Arguments = "/config c:\accessruntime2010\config.xml"

#Launch Process
Start-Process -FilePath $Process -ArgumentList $Arguments -Verb runAs
```

Comment: Will the user be prompted for a password?

Comment: Does this script run from the Client that needs it installed or can I run it from my Admin station?

Comment: The script above will just execute it as an administrator. If you want it to prompt for credentials, then you will have to add in the `-Credential` parameter. If the users have no permissions, then maybe the best way to do this is to use Group Policy to install it. We install lots of programs, and run lots of scripts using Group Policy. If you want to selectively install programs from your machine, then maybe PowerShell remoting is what you want see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx